# Window size differs in different Windows versions when only using WS_OVERLAPPED

Tags: c, winapi, windows-7, windows-xp

When using the following code to create a Window:

```
CreateWindowEx(0, "WinClass", "My Title", WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_SYSMENU, 261, 172, 594, 384, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
```

I get different Window sizes under Windows XP and Windows 7:

[image]

However, when I add the `WS_THICKFRAME` style, the problem is solved:

```
CreateWindowEx(0, "WinClass", "My Title", WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_SYSMENU | WS_THICKFRAME, 261, 172, 594, 384, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
```

But unfortunately `WS_THICKFRAME` makes the Window resizable which I don't want.

---

**Edit:**

What I want it to remain the same size across different versions of Windows is the client area.

Comment: Are the coordinates the inner or outer size of the window?

Comment: @Olaf What do you mean by the inner or outer size of a window?

Comment: Very hard to see what the actual problem is here. Or indeed what your question is. Can you expand to make it clear to us what question you would like answered.

Comment: The thickness of the window frame changes under different versions of Windows. Best to start with the desired client size (what Olaf means by "inner size") - the area *inside* the frame - and use `AdjustWindowRectEx` to calculate the total size.

Comment: Are you aware that the frame adds to the size of the usable (inner) area?

Comment: I have edited my question.

Comment: @Olaf: It's called *client area*. If you wish to play with the Windows devs, get accustomed to their terminology. (The non-client area is *"usable"* as well, btw.)

Comment: @IInspectable: No need to play with the kids. I've enough serious work to do. So, thanks, but look for someone else to play with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for [AdjustWindowRect function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632665%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> Calculates the required size of the window rectangle, based on the
>   desired client-rectangle size. The window rectangle can then be passed
>   to the CreateWindow function to create a window whose client area is
>   the desired size.